# Does the iPhone 6 support NFC scanning that will open up the Safari browser?

Tags: ios, ios8, nfc, iphone-6

Apple just announced that the iPhone 6 will have an NFC chip.

Does this mean that you will now be able to scan a NFC tag and it will open up the Safari browser?